# How can I access JSON variables in an array with the same names?

Tags: json, swift, google-books

This is my first time parsing JSON and I'm using the Google Books api. I'm trying to access ISBN10s and ISBN13s, which [this page](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using) shows as part of the response.
 I don't understand though, how to access them separately as they are named the same thing? Here's the part I'm talking about:

```
"industryIdentifiers": [
   {
    "type": "ISBN_10",
    "identifier": "055380457X"
   },
   {
    "type": "ISBN_13",
    "identifier": "9780553804577"
   }
  ]
```

And here's the code I've blindly been trying to get to work:

```
 if let isbns: Array = volumeInfo["industryIdentifiers"] as? [String] {
      let isbnTen = isbns[0] {
        book.isbn10 = isbnTen["identifier"] as? String
      }
 }
```

Currently Xcode complains that "Variable used within its own initial value" on the last line.

Comment: `if let isbnTen…` not `let isbnTen…`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It works for me:

```
var arrFinalArray = [yourObjectClass]()
if let isbns: Array = volumeInfo["industryIdentifiers"] as? [String] {
    for i in 0..<isbns.count{
        let book = yourObjectClass()
        let value = isbns[i]
        book.isbn10 = value["identifier"] as? String
        arrFinalArray.append(book)
    }        
}
```